# How can I make a call with/to multiple people on the same public IP?

Tags: internet, ip, skype

I need to set up a Skype call in a net cafe. The problem is that every PC in the net cafe uses the same IP address and because of this, no more than two people can join the same call on Skype.

(I need to do this because later I will capture everybody's webcam and stream them.)

Comment: If Skype won't let you, use another similar software.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to a public network, you are using DHCP to obtain your IP addressing for your device. Without going into long detail, there's not really a way that your two computers have the same IP address on your local network. If you are using two Windows computers, I would open run.exe and type in ipconfig to find out for yourself. This sounds like  it's an application issue.